# Multiplying a subset of matrix to another matrix using lapack/blas

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication, lapack, blas

I want to multiply a subset of matrix A to another matrix, using dgemm or anyother lapack/blas function. I think that since elements of the submatrix may not be contiguous, I cannot use dgemm directly without copying the submatrix to another space. So, when this submatrix is itself large, it may be very inefficient to the extent that I think it may be better for me to write the code for multiplication for this specific problem in C. Since copying and then using the lapack/blas itself, may not be efficient at all. I am using lapack/blas in matlab as a mex file.

My questions are

1- Is there any function of lapack/blas which can work on submatrices in multiplication?
2- If it isn't, is it better to write the code for multiplication directly or is it better to copy submatrix to another matrix and use dgemm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually `dgemm` is designed for submatrix multiplication. You just need to make right use of the starting pointers for each matrix and the arguments `LDA`, `LDB`, `LDC`.

The `C` variant of BLAS is :

```
void cblas_dgemm (const CBLAS_LAYOUT layout, const CBLAS_TRANSPOSE TransA, const CBLAS_TRANSPOSE TransB, const int M, const int N, const int K, const double alpha, const double *A, const int lda, const double *B, const int ldb, const double beta, double *C, const int ldc);
```

Say that you have matrices:

- `A(15x10)`
- `B(10x20)`
- `C(15x20)`

Calling `dgemm` for `Column Major` matrix storage :

```
cblas_dgemm (CblasColMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 15, 20, 10, 1., A, 15, B, 10, 1., C, 15);
```

Suppose that you need to call `dgemm` passing the submatrices:

- `As(3x2)` starting at point `(2,1)` of `A`
- `Bs(2x5)` starting at point `(3,5)` of `B`
- `Cs(3x5)` starting at point `(4,2)` of `C`

The `N`, `M`, `K` will change to 3, 5, 2, but the `LDXs` will remain same as above. Then you have to pass the right pointers to `dgemm` so that they will point to the start of each submatrix. Since you have `C` numbering you have to subtract one from each coordinate.

- `As` starting point is `A + (1+0*15)`
- `Bs` starting point is `B + (2+4*10)`
- `Cs` starting point is `C + (3+1*15)`

  ```
  cblas_dgemm (CblasColMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 3, 5, 2, 1., A+1, 15, B+42, 10, 1., C+18, 15);
  ```

The idea of `N` `LDA` is to say that I have a matrix `A(LDA,*)` but I will use the upper submatrix `As(N,*)`. In the examples case you do not want to use the upper submatrix but some other inside `A`. In this case you create a new pointer `A+1` to matrix. Now `As` is an upper submatrix of `A+1`.

Similarly calling the Fortran's original `dgemm` function from `C` will be

```
    char NoTrans = `N`;
    int N = 3;
    int M = 5;
    int K = 2;
    int LDA = 15;
    int LDB = 10;
    int LDC = 15;
    double alpha = 1.0;
    double beta = 1.0;
    dgemm (&NoTrans, &NoTrans, N, M, K, alpha, A+1, LDA, B+42, LDB, beta, C+18, LDC);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Could you please explain a little more what it means to use it this way?
 How blas_dgemm finds the next elements of the submatrix given that it doesnot know the start of the matrix and size of each column? and can I use this in lapack/blas in matlab? sorry I am so new to this.

Comment: @user85361 I just mentioned cblas equivalent because you mentioned `C`. You can use original Fortran's `dgemm` in your mex file as well. I will update the answer

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much.

Comment: How to multiply two submatrices when we have [0/1] indices for row and columns, so they may not be contiguous?

Comment: @user85361 I dont get the "[0/1] indices". Please explain

Comment: In matlab you can have logical indexing, e.g., lind = myVec>0. In this way you have indices which 1 means it is in the computation and 0 means it's not.

Comment: That's not possible with BLAS